# ReactJS + Websocket + Context = Max update depth exceeded

Tags: reactjs, websocket

I'm having a ReactJS "Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded" error occuring in my WebsocketContext component and I'm not sure why and hoping someone might be able to shed some light.  I'll share as much code as I can.

(I'm still a ReactJS apprentice so I completely acknowledge my approach(es) could be very wrong!)

My small SPA will have a Websocket connection to AWS, which receives Codepipeline Events to populate a ReactJS UI to display the current state of pipelines (we have a lot of them, 600+)

Following several Stackoverflow and internet examples, I created a `WebsocketContext` to handle the connectivity and message receiving, and then wrapped my main component(s) in App.js within that context so they had access to the messages and connection.

My main issue right now seems to be with how the `ws.current.onmessage` is behaving as, after the initial load of pipelines, approx 650, give it about 10 mins and any trickle through updates that call `setMessage()` cause this:

```
Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render. 3 react_devtools_backend.js:4026:25
    overrideMethod react_devtools_backend.js:4026
    React 5
    onmessage WebsocketContext.js:57
    (Async: EventHandlerNonNull)
    connect WebsocketContext.js:56
    WebsocketProvider WebsocketContext.js:79
    React 12
    workLoop scheduler.development.js:266
    flushWork scheduler.development.js:239
    performWorkUntilDeadline scheduler.development.js:533
    (Async: EventHandlerNonNull)
    js scheduler.development.js:571
    js scheduler.development.js:633
    factory react refresh:6
    Webpack 24
```

Below is a stripped down version of the `WebsocketContext.js`

```js
export function WebsocketProvider({children}) {
    const [message, setMessage] = useState(null);
    const [isReady, setIsReady] = useState(false); 

    const ws = useRef(null);
 
    const connect = () => {
        ws.current = new WebSocket(PIPELINE_WEBSOCKET_URL) 
        ws.current.onerror = (event) => {  }
        ws.current.onopen = () => {
            console.log(`[${getTimestamp()}] Opened connection to '${PIPELINE_WEBSOCKET_URL}'`);
            setIsReady(true);
        }

        ws.current.onclose = () => {
            setTimeout(function () {
                console.log(`[${getTimestamp()}] Closed connection to '${PIPELINE_WEBSOCKET_URL}'`);
                setIsReady(false);
                connect();
            }, WEBSOCKET_RECONNECT_DELAY);
        } 

        ws.current.onmessage = (event) => {
            setMessage(JSON.parse(event.data)); // <-- Problem thrown from here!
        }

        const wsCurrent = ws.current; 

        return () => {
            console.log(`[${getTimestamp()}] Closing connection to '${PIPELINE_WEBSOCKET_URL}'...`);
            wsCurrent.close();

        };
    } 

    useEffect(() => {
        connect()
    }, []) 

    const ret = [isReady, message, ws.current?.send.bind(ws.current)];
 
    return (
        <WebsocketContext.Provider value={ret}>
            {children}
        </WebsocketContext.Provider>
    )
} 

export default WebsocketContext;
```

Here is a component within my `App.js` that implements this context:

```js
export default function ParentPipelineDashboard() {
    const [groupedPipelineObjects, setGroupedPipelineObjects] = useState({});
    const [message, send] = useContext(WebsocketContext); 

    useEffect(() => {
        if (message) {
            updatePipelineTypeObjects(message)
        }
    }, [message]); 

    const updatePipelineTypeObjects = (data) => {
        try {
            const pipelineName = data.pipelineName;
            const pipelineGroup = data.pipelineGroupName;           
            setGroupedPipelineObjects(prevState => {

                const groups = {...prevState};
                if (groups[pipelineGroup]) {
                    groups[pipelineGroup] = {
                        ...groups[pipelineGroup], [pipelineName]: data,
                    };
                } else {
                    groups[pipelineGroup] = {
                        [pipelineName]: data,
                    };
                }
                return groups;
            })
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error))
        }
    }   
}
```

That `ParentPipelineDashboard` creates a larger complete 'Object' of all my pipeline data in such a way that makes it easy to extract what I need and when I need it, stored in `groupedPipelineObjects`.

The `groupedPipelineObjects` object then feeds many child-components within the `ParentPipelineDashboard` component in order to create rows of data specific to each pipeline, progress bars for the pipelines, info buttons, details, etc.

So, looking at the chain (i think?):

- WebsocketContext receives AWS events and sets each one received to
  `message` in its `useState()`
- The `ParentPipelineDashboard` component
  makes use of the `message` variable in the context to create its own
  complete Object
- That complete Object is used to feed
  child-components.

Eventually it complains about the depth and points to the `onmessage` function in the context component.  But i don't understand why -- surely React can handle it being used that often and that many times?

Is there a correct/more efficient way to approach this?

Thanks!

I have already moved the Websocket into a context instead of sitting in the original component for reuse.  I tried to create a separate function that the onmessage would call instead of directly calling the setMessage().

I expect that it shouldn’t complain about the max depth being exceeded